# Jquery not functioning in Django html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am trying to use some Jquery to highlight some rows in a table. My project is built using Django. When I navigate to the page that has the table I can see in my logs..

```
[16/May/2020 18:12:43] "GET /media/row.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

So I know the JS is getting loaded correctly. I can also look at my source and see that it is linked properly.

My table is:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr class="clickable-row">
                    <th scope="col">Property</th>
                    <th scope="col">Expected Value</th>
                    <th scope="col">Actual Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="clickable-row">
                    {% for lis in json %}
                        <tr class="clickable-row">
                        {% for i in lis %}
                            <td style="word-wrap: break-word">{{i}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And the Jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

I have tested that the Jquery actually works outside of my project in a Codepen. I have tried adding the Jquery directly in my page that requires it.

My inspect page looks like:

```
 </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/media/row.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you log something to console to ensure that event function is calling correctly? And can you change the class of any row in your table manually to "active" to see that effect is what you want or not?

Comment: Hmm. Changing to <tr class="active"> did nothing.

Comment: I guess you have forgotten to add css files correctly in your template. Can you check them?

Comment: I have them added correctly. I was able to apply the class 'table-active' and that worked. I changed that in the JQuery and still not changing row color.

Comment: Did you update your /media/row.js file and hit the file without cache? The jquery function fires correctly, the error should be something in your setup. Can you restart django server and open the page on a private window?

Comment: Yes I did all of that and no luck.

Comment: Do you have ```load static files``` template tag at the start of your django template?

Comment: Yes. I use a base.html and I populate the body with different templates. But I do have ```{% load static %}``` at the top of my base.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by adding another script to my base.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am not sure why that worked and how that is different from the one I have which is:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then I decided to remove the integrity and crossorigin from my existing Jquery source and it works. Not sure what went wrong but I decided to remove those from all of my external files.